# Angular component doesn't see function from service

Tags: angular

I'm quite new with Angular. I have service where I have fuction to post survey and component. My component has problem with service, it doesn't see it. Also with UserIdleModule, I need to to use @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserIdleService)) to make it work but this doesn't work with my service, I'm getting error: core.js:19866 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addSurvey' of undefined.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SurveyComponent } from './survey/survey.component';

import { UserIdleModule } from 'angular-user-idle';
import { HttpClientModule }    from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: 10, timeout: 10, ping: 1})
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SurveyComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

survey.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SurveyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private apiUrl = 'api/url';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  addSurvey (survey: JSON): Observable<JSON> {
    return this.http.post<JSON>(this.apiUrl, survey, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newSurvey: JSON) => console.log(`added survey w/ id=${newSurvey}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<JSON>('addSurvey'))
    );
  }
}
```

survey.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, forwardRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserIdleService } from 'angular-user-idle';
import * as Survey from 'survey-angular';
import * as widgets from "surveyjs-widgets";
import Sortable from 'sortablejs';
import { SurveyService } from '../survey.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey',
  templateUrl: './survey.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey.component.less']
})

export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => UserIdleService)) private userIdle: UserIdleService, private surveyService: SurveyService) { }

  ...(some code)...

  this.surveyService.addSurvey(JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 3));

}
```

Comment: where do you write the "this.surveyService.addSurvey"? Is it in the ngOnInit?

Comment: Your issue isn't the function here, it's the service itself being undefined when you are calling it. Make sure to execute the call inside the `ngOnInit` or in a method that well be called after the constructor has been executed.

Comment: plz make sure that you imported SurveyService from the right path, as I've played with your code, looks everything is fine, plz have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bw95uc

Comment: Yes, this.surveyService.addSurvey is in ngOnInit

Comment: your code should work, and if you want to use useridleService you should provideInRoot too for not use this @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserIdleService)) that is not very common.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put SurveyService in app.module.ts in the `providers` array and simply use dependency injection in your component:

app.module.ts

```
import { SurveyService } from '<path-to-service>/survey.service';

NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: 10, timeout: 10, ping: 1})
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SurveyComponent
  ],
  providers: [SurveyService], <-- here you provide the service
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

survey.component.ts

```
import { SurveyService } from '<path-to-service>/survey.service';

constructor(
  private surverService: SurveyService,
  ...
) { }
```

Comment: His service is already being provided from the Injectable decorator (`providedIn: 'root'`), which is a better way to do it for tree shaking.

Comment: @Morphush oh, you're absolutely right, I didn't notice that provideIn part :O

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the service inner a method or in the init. Or if you can share all the code of the component.

```
export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => UserIdleService)) private userIdle: UserIdleService, private surveyService: SurveyService) { }

  ...(some code)...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.surveyService.addSurvey(JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 3));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe it's not visible in code I posted but yes it's inside ngOnInit() {}